# Parent and child process segregation and child listing

Tags: excel, vbscript

Please read the following template:

```
PID     Status      LPID

10       Closed      25
11       Open        25
31       Open        31
25       Closed      25
54       Open        31
17       Open        17
20       Closed      31
88       closed      77
77       closed      77
```

Now when PID!= LPID, that PID is defined as CPID(Child Process ID),Otherwise it is a PPID(Parent process ID)

Now I am looking for a code which will tell which is parent and Which is child- means marking them in another sheet.At the Same time i want to list down all CPID,with PPID in the same row,If any PPID has child Processes themselves. Output would be look like below

```
PID   Type Of Process?    Child List
10       Child
11       Child
31       Parent              54 20
25       Parent              10 11
54       Child
17       Parent
20       Child
88       Child
77       Parent              88
```

I have written a code using VBScript,but with the actual sheet it is too slow. For 2500 data it is taking close to 1 hour.So I Want a more faster process than my one.

Could you help here using VBscript?

***Code1:***

```
  Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Object for W2W Report Dump


  strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"
  objExcel1.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1

  Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
  Set objSheet2 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    IntRow1=1
 Do While objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value <> ""

    IntRow2=4
    IntChildListColumn=3

    If objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,2).Value="Parent" Then

        Do While objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 1).Value <> ""

             If objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2,11).Value=objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,1).Value And objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2,11).Value <> objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2,1).Value Then

                 objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,IntChildListColumn).Value=objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2,1).Value
                 IntChildListColumn=IntChildListColumn+1

             End If

      IntRow2=IntRow2+1

      Loop

   End If

 IntRow1=IntRow1+1

Loop
```

***Code2:***

```
 Flag=0
 IntColTemp=1
 IntRowTemp=3

 Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Object for Condition Dump


 strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"
 objExcel1.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1

 Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Set objSheet2 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

 IntRow1=4
 IntRow2=1

Do While objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value <> ""

  objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 1).Value = objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value


   IntColTemp=1
   Flag=0
  'This will travarse to the Parent Business Process ID column horizantally in the excel.
  Do While Flag=0

  If objSheet1.Cells(IntRowTemp,IntColTemp).Value="Parent Business Process ID" Then

      Flag=1       

  End If

      IntColTemp=IntColTemp+1


Loop
      IntColTemp=IntColTemp-1
      'MsgBox(IntColTemp)

  Strcmp1=trim(objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1, 1).Value)
  Strcmp2=trim(objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,IntColTemp).Value)

  If Strcmp1=Strcmp2 Then

      objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 2).Value="Parent" 

  Else

      objSheet2.Cells(IntRow2, 2).Value="child"

  End If


   IntRow1=IntRow1+1
   IntRow2=IntRow2+1

  Loop
```

Comment: @j0k can you help me here?

Comment: Can any body help me out here,by providing any suggestions?

Comment: please read the FAQ. In particular please understand that it is expected that you tried something already and post that in your question. Then we can suggest improvements to your script. If you arent a programmer but wanting to become one, please follow a training or hire a freelancer to do the work for you!

Comment: Okay I am posting my code here.But it is heavily time consuming to wait. The total response time is too much with my code.

Comment: understood, please post the code so we can look into it and also be more precise on the time it takes (10 seconds? 12 minutes? 2 hours?)

Comment: The whole code is taking close to 1 hour for only 1450 data in the sheet.So i want to make it less time consuming. that's the whole purpose!!

Comment: one thing that might be faster is using `Value2` in stead of `Value`

Comment: I didn't get your point Sir :-D

Comment: you use `Cells.Value` everywhere, there is also something called `Value2`, that is mostly faster to use...

Comment: OK,so.but the Value2 will fetch the same value as value was fetching right? But Can you design it another way? or any improvement area?

Comment: It will fetch the same thing. It will just disregard any formatting and thus is faster (and also therefore will not give conflicts over date formatting other then the US dateformatting. I fear I cannot be of more assistance, but with the code provided others will probably jump in!

Comment: Just looking briefly I would try to eliminate the inner Do While loop, the one that sets Flag to 1 when it finds the column.  You should only need to run it once to find the column, unless there are multiple columns or something.  So take the inner Do While out of the outer Do While.

Comment: Deusx.. its very typical to rewrite,So can you frame it for me with a shorter one,or if possible without using any Loop n all..?

Comment: @K_B Can you help me in this post - "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841078/pivot-table-data-population/13841249#13841249"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggested improvements:

In case you really have the screen open the excel: set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at start of your code (and `True` and the end)

Set the Application.Calculation to manual. At start of your code: 
`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and at the end back to automatic: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`. In case this was not automatic per se, you could also first store the original setting into a local variable and restore that value at the end.

Use VBA to see if performance is better there (if VBA would be a valid option for you)

Use `Value2` in stead of `Value`, this property is faster to consult.

Reduce the number of Loops especially when you are looking for specific values in a range.
You could alternatively use Excel Lookup & Reference functions (such as VLookup), those might run more efficient and faster.

Comment: could you please edit my code with key things you adviced me to do.I will be more happy,as i don't have that much knowledege in VBA. just make some thing magic with my code. I did the jobe in two parts of code.can it be combined? This way it would help to reduce the number of codes. You are saying me to decrease the Loops - but i couldn't understand how to do so,as my logic still in my dump head :-).. that's why i approached to you people to leran something advanced programming rather than the classical coding. hope you will help :-)

Comment: @user1897085 I feel that there is a knowledge gap as I and some others have provided you with things to try, but the only respons we seem to get it cvan you please rewrite my code... Thats not the idea also we cannot see if this will in the end be good enough for you when you tried this or that. So I strongly advise you to get the suggestions incorporated and post back any improvement in your running time and if it now suffices.

Comment: I tried the Value2,but it is destroying the date format when copying from one cell to another. but I was looking for if two scripts can be combined into one!

Comment: I indeed said it will disregard formatting, if you want the date formatting back you can format the cell with the date formatting you want. A date in VBA (and many other languages) isnt anything else then a number with a date format "sauce" over it. Your question is what can you try/do to improve performance. If you want to ask another question (how can I make two scripts into one script) then please post that question as a new one.

Comment: Okay,I will! But then i need to give again all the description there.

Comment: May I get some help from you on this post?