# Row data and column data count using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

How using VBScript I can count the number of rows filled with data and how many column has a value for a particular row?

```
       Col1 Col2 Col3 ........ColN-1  ColN+1...ColN+2.......ColN+2

 Row1   A         B                             Null         Null
 Row2   1    2    Y                             .
 Row3        2                                  .
 Row4        P    Z 
  .                                             .
  .
  .
 RowN-2                                         .
 RowN-1                         T        L      Null.......Null
 RowN                     S
 RowN+1 Null ........(till the last column of the excel sheet that its version supprts.)
```

So here my required Loop iteration which i would use for my other logic is N for rows and for columns it would be N+1
***Update***

```
   Option Explicit

   Dim rg,CountBlank

   For C=0 to 10

    Set rg = Ob6.Range(Ob6.Columns(c),Ob6.Columns(c))
    CountBlank = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rg)
    MsgBox("Column"&C": "&"Has"&(rg.rows.Count-CountBlank))
 Next
```

Thanks

Comment: nice question, but please show us any efforts you've made to try to do this. We can help you get past your stuck points, but no one is really inclined to write a full script for you. Also, do you want vbscript? or are you wanting VBA (inside an XL application)?

Comment: VbScript i do want...But i don't have any idea how to do so? So here i posted.Please help me out.

Comment: You can use the `oXLAp.WorksheetFunction.CountA()`. I can give you an example but as Scott suggested, give it a try and then post back with what you tried and where are you stuck and we will take it from there :)

Comment: Have you written any vbscript to get yourself started?

Comment: I tried this one,But it can give only column data count. I don't have any idea about the row data count.

Comment: Still in my above post you can see for Col1 and Row4 has no data.Still i need to loop thorugh till that row to meet my other requirement. This is the pain for me. As Col1 can have data for some rows and for some not. So please help me

Comment: I need to loop thorugh till that row for which iff a single column contains data.

Comment: Do you need to loop through each column until the last row that has data? Or just the first row that is blank? And the same for the rows .. loop through until the last column? or just until the first blank column? There's many ways to write the script, but I would rather give you exactly what you need.

Comment: Let me clear myself once again- I need the row count as till that row,which has data for its single column.Means row count will be stopped when script find a row which has no data for all columns in the sheet. Vice-verse for column count. Updated the description also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get you started. It will show for each row the number of columns that have data, and for each column the number of rows that have data. You can then modify it to more suit your needs:

**EDIT:** Code updated to capture first row / column with only 1 column / row of data:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rg

'loop through columns
For C=0 to 10

    Set rg = Ob6.Columns(c)

    If objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rg) =1 Then

       Exit For

    End If

Next

MsgBox("Column" & C & " is first column with only 1 row")

'loop through rows
For C=0 to 10

    Set rg = Ob6.Rows(c)

    If objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rg) =1 Then

       Exit For

    End If

Next

MsgBox("Column" & C & " is first row with only 1 column")
```

Comment: I just modified my case description for you.Hope it will be helpful for you.But don't delete the code you posted right now.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for your help! I know you are the only people,can unstuck me from anywhere.:-)

Comment: Can you help me in my below post,where i have pasted the code i am using,but its too slow. And also I want those two codes to be combined into a single one.Please help me there. That is a bottleneck for me still.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835758/parent-and-child-process-segregation-and-child-listing/13843834#13843834